# Can you use Webmatrix.Data to connect to MySql stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, webmatrix

I know that you can use Webmatrix.Data with MySql, but is it able to be used with MySql's stored procs? It does with SqlServer's procs obviously, not with Oracle's procs and I need to know if it will with MySql?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The CommandType for the DbCommand object that the Database helper wraps is CommandType.Text, so you can't simply pass the name of a stored procedure into the Query or Execute method. You have to prefix it with EXECUTE (or EXEC) with SQL Server. [The equivalent for MySQL seems to be CALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html). I suspect there is something similar for Oracle too.